# How to use null as default value - Compose mutableState

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, mutablestateof

I have a need like on first time on UI load the **mutableStateOf Boolean** value must be **null** , instead of default value as true/false similar to regular boolean value in Kotlin as

```
var isBooleanValue: Boolean = null
```

what I need is as below

```
var isClassAccessedAtleastOnce = remember {  mutableStateOf(null) }
```

Kindly let me know is there any possibility from the useCase

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Define type of variable as

```
var isClassAccessedAtleastOnce = remember { mutableStateOf<Boolean?>(null) }
```